# jQuery Mobile, set footer to bottom of screen without using data-position="fixed", is it possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to set the footer to attach at the bottom of the screen, this can easily be done by setting `<div data-role="footer" data-id="persistent_navbar" data-position="fixed">` as detailed on the jquery [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html)

However, that seems to yield the following undesired output :

[image]

So by removing the `data-position="fixed"`, the footer then neatly fits into the target content width, but it floats up underneath the main content, like so :

[image]

**Question:** How can I attach the footer to the bottom of the screen, but at the same time ensuring that the footer doesn't overflow from its container? The ultimate goal is to have a scrolling list between the header and footer.

This is my HTML for the above :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
        <title>SmartConf</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SmartConf.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body onload="WL.Client.init({})" id="content" style="display: none">

        <div data-role="page">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                </div><!-- /header -->

                <div data-role="content">
                <a href="home.html" data-role="button">Enter</a>    

                </div><!-- /content -->

                <div data-role="footer" data-id="persistent_navbar">
                    <h4>Some footer here</h4>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /page -->



        <script src="js/SmartConf.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `SmartConf.css` :

```
/*Worklight container div */
#content {
    height: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725351/jquery-nav-bars-appearing-outside-of-the-content-width

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
<ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TabBar" class="tab_bar"
data-dojo-props='fixed: "bottom"' syncWithViews="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change this:

```
#content {
    height: 460px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 320px;
}
```

into this:

```
#content {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

or in other words, why do you put constrains on your width and height?